# How to use a pre-trained keras model for inference in tf.data.Dataset.map?

Tags: python, r, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-datasets

I have a pre-trained model, and I'm trying to build another model that takes as input the output of the previous model. I don't want to train the models end-to-end, and want to use the first model for inference only. The first model was trained using `tf.data.Dataset` pipeline, and my first inclination was to integrate the model as just another `dataset.map()` operation at the tail of the pipeline, but I'm having issues with that. I've encountered 20 different errors in the process, each unrelated to the prior one. The batch-normalization layer particularly seems to be a pain-point for this.

Below is a minimal starter example that illustrates the issue. It's written in R but answers in python are also welcome.

I'm using tensorflow-gpu version 1.13.1 and keras from `tf.keras`

```r
library(reticulate)
library(tensorflow)
library(keras)
library(tfdatasets)
use_implementation("tensorflow")

model_weights_path <- 'model-weights.h5'

arr <- function(...) 
  np_array(array(seq_len(prod(unlist(c(...)))), unlist(c(...))), dtype = 'float32')

new_model <- function(load_weights = TRUE) {
  model <- keras_model_sequential() %>% 
    layer_conv_1d(5, 5, activation = 'relu', input_shape = shape(150, 10)) %>%
    layer_batch_normalization() %>%
    layer_flatten() %>%
    layer_dense(10, activation = 'softmax')
  if (load_weights)
    load_model_weights_hdf5(model, model_weights_path)
  freeze_weights(model)
  model
}

if(!file.exists(model_weights_path)) {
  model <- new_model(FALSE) 
  save_model_weights_hdf5(model, model_weights_path)
}

model <- new_model()

data <- arr(20, 150, 10)
ds <- tfdatasets::tensors_dataset(data) %>% 
  dataset_repeat()

ds2 <- ds %>% 
  dataset_map(function(x) {
    model(x)
  })

try(nb <- next_batch(ds2))

sess <- k_get_session()
it <- make_iterator_initializable(ds2)
sess$run(iterator_initializer(it))
nb <- it$get_next()

try(sess$run(nb))

sess$run(tf$initialize_all_variables())

try(sess$run(nb))
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will not answer your question directly as I am not familiar with R. But I have recently built an input pipeline using `tf.data`.

The `generate_images` function is mapped using `.map` and uses a trained generator model to generate new images.

```
gen_model = tf.keras.models.load_model(artifact_dir+'/'+generators[-1], compile=False)

NOISE_DIM = 100

def generate_images(l):
    # generate images using the trained generator
    noise = tf.random.normal([BATCH_SIZE, NOISE_DIM])
    images = gen_model(noise)

    # prepare the images for resize_and_preprocess function
    images = tf.squeeze(images, axis=-1)
    images = images*0.5+0.5
    images = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(images, dtype=tf.uint8)

    return images

genloader = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors([1])

genloader = (
    genloader
    .map(generate_images, num_parallel_calls=AUTO)
    .map(resize_and_preprocess, num_parallel_calls=AUTO)
    .prefetch(AUTO)
)
```

Regarding Batch Normalization, it behaves differently during the training and inference phase. In Python-based TensorFlow one needs to pass `training=False` when using a pretrained model that has batch normalization layer.